# Removing Paypal iframe in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, iframe, paypal

We have a react application and are using paypal to login. We give paypal a redirect url to return to our app. It renders our page inside of the paypal iframe.

Does anyone know how to remove the iframe when the page loads. I have tried:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (window != top) {
        top.location.replace('localhost:3002/journey')
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: _“I have tried: […]”_ - and …? What happened, what errors did you get?

Comment: Nothing happens. It re-renders my page inside of the iframe.

Comment: It ends up executing the empty else clause. If I console log inside of both blocks.

Comment: Have you tried to decide this based on the current URL instead? Check for whether it is the specified redirect URI, or add an additional GET parameter to that or something, if not otherwise discernible from a “normal” call.

Comment: I tried that. I also tried doing what paypal suggests, top.location.replace, on the succeeding condition and it does nothing in React. Has anyone solved this problem in React?

Comment: Is the iframe sandboxed in some way, so that it might not allow for top level navigation?

Comment: No. We are testing this in staging. Testing locally is a nightmare. The issue seems to be that top.location.replace does nothing. I'm guessing react is not triggering an update with this sort of direct manipulation. Not sure what else to try though.

Comment: Don’t see what staging vs local has to do with what attributes the iframe might have set? And unless react had explicitly overwritten `top.location.replace`, I don’t see how it could interfere that way either.